# How to make motor spin the other way

Tags: motors, circuit-design

Let’s say I want two motors in parallel in a circuit (so they get the same Voltage), and wanted one motor to spin anti-clockwise and the other clockwise- is it possible?

I thought by flipping one of the motors polarity, it would?

I want both motors to project a ball the same way, like a tennis ball launcher

Comment: Yes..............

Comment: The devil is in the details, but yes.  Details: DC, AC, Stepper, BLDC, three-phase.

Comment: Mount one on the left and one on the right of the gear they drive.

Comment: Hi, so I want them to both effectively project something the same direction like a tennis ball launcher

Comment: what does that mean? ... what mechanism is used to project an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the motors are 'simple' DC motors, then yes, reversing the polarity on one of them will generally reverse the direction of rotation.

Any other type of motor (AC, etc.) probably won't work this way.

If you're building a 'tennis ball launcher' like device you can get the same effect by simply physically mounting the motors so they spin in opposite directions (ie, rotate one so the two motor shafts are still parallel but facing each other/pointing in opposite directions).

If you give more information about the particular motor you'll probably get a better answer...

Comment: AC normal induction motors definitely spin backwards if you wire them backwards

Comment: @TigerGuy I didn't want to run down all of the possibilities, just point out that anything other than a 'simple' DC motor is problematic.

Comment: Hi, I was thinking of using DC motors. Only thing is, i don’t have enough room if I place one of them like that- so I thought that would have to try get one to spin anti-clockwise then instead of re mounting it? Would it be okay if I put them both parallel to each other in the circuit and one flipped around so that it’s plus and minus flip please and then would one spin the other way please?

Comment: @Herbert As this answer clearly states, if you are using DC motors then you should be able to reverse direction by reversing polarity.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could reverse both polarity of Motor OR battery on that circuit Herbert- but reversing polarity of battery though it will reverse both motors- not just one!

That’s saying it’s two motors in parallel with power source